# How to obtain adapter from fragment in activity without getting null pointer exception?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-cursoradapter

As the title say, what's the way to get instance of `CursorAdapter` created in my `CustomListFragment`. `MainActivity` layout contains `CustomListFragment` in layout file. I added method `getAdapter()` in `CustomListFragment`, and in `MainActivity` I created instance of fragment, but when I call method from `MainActivity` in which I have method call of `getAdapter()` i.e. `adapter = customListFragment.getAdapter();` exeception occurs.

Is there any way to avoid that duplicate code and do all method calls and adapter initializations in one class? Also, I tried with interface, but no luck.

Comment: at first glance it looks like you got things wired wrong. Why would activity  need not own adapter access directly?

Comment: I have another activity for adding items to db, but, when I return back to main activity, added item is missing until I refresh and change cursor. You can see code at [github link](https://github.com/ridjis/Glosar/tree/master/app/src/main/java/rs/ridjis/glosar) in folders activity and fragments.

Comment: still, activity should not be involved here. see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have another activity for adding items to db, but, when I return back to main activity, added item is missing until I refresh and change cursor.

It should suffice to change cursor in your fragment's `onResume()`. No need to make parent activity involved.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that it is gonna call method twice, on create and on restart, I forgot that fragment recreates everytime from onCreateView.

Comment: if you do set your cursor in `onCreate()` just remove this code and make it all in `onResume()`.